# vanishing output with expect_out(buffer)

Tags: output, tcl, expect, puts

Used language: TCL / Expect

When I print the output of the expect_out(buffer), it removes the whole printed line for some kind of reason. I have no clue on what is doing this. I've even broken down the "puts" output with -nonewline to be sure and this output also vanished for this line.

Code:

```
     set var $expect_out(0,string)
     foreach line [split $var \n] {
         puts -nonewline "line: "
         puts $line
     }
```

output:

```
    somedata
    line: somemoredata
    line: evensomemoredata
```

expected output:

```
    line: somedata
    line: somemoredata
    line: evensomemoredata
```

What can cause this output? How can I even troubleshoot this?

****Edit after answer:***

*To help others with this problem in Expect, it helps to add the following command in your expect script to troubleshoot:*

```
    exp_internal 1
```

*This shows everything that is going on, including the values in the buffer that were returned.*

Comment: Probably "somedata" contains a carriage return (\r) character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in Expect, `\n` chars in the spawned program's output will be converted to `\r\n`. You can manually remove the `\r` chars like this:

```
set var $expect_out(0,string)
set var [regsub -all "\r" $var ""]
... ...
```

Comment: that helped :-) for some kind of reason my output gets a "Run.." prepended but that's probably nothing to do with this. I solved the issue with your solution. Thanks!